# Binding a window's height to gridsplitter (inside a view box) movement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Basically I have an application which is nested in this manner. Assume that this is a simple layout and I have more rows and gridsplitters inbetween each of them.

```
<Window>
  <Viewbox>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height = 100/>
      <RowDefinition Height = 100/>
      </Grid.RowDefinition>
      <Gridsplitter Grid.Row =0/>
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

The viewbox is for the user to resize the window and have the app grow or shrink depending on their preference. I also added a gridsplitter to resize the rows of the grid so that they can reduce unnecessary tabs. However, the viewbox/window remained the same size, making the function of a gridsplitter pointless. Is there a way for the viewbox/window to resize *accordingly* when the gridsplitter is moved? E.g when I pull up the gridsplitter and hide a grid.row, the main window will also pull up and hide the extra blank space.

Comment: I guess the issue here is that your heights (in the example) are static. You might want to do something like

<Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition MinHeight = "100" Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition MinHeight = "100" Height="*">
      </Grid.RowDefinition>
      <Gridsplitter Grid.Row =0/>
    </Grid>

But in my opinion the viewbox solution is not the best one. Consider making the UI responsive to the available space instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBoxes can be awkward and fiddly; content inside them does not stretch as you would expect it to in, say - a grid. 
The ViewBox exists to take an element that has an absolute value (i.e. `height=10`, `width=10`) and allow it to be resized.

Try the following modification i made to your code:

```
 <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid Width="1280" Height="720">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Green" />
            <GridSplitter Width="100"
                          Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,-10"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          Cursor="SizeNS"
                          ResizeDirection="Rows" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

The two rows can now be resized by dragging the grey GridSplitter, and the entire grid resizes as you resize the window in a uniform fashion.

The other issue is you giving both of your rows absolute sizes (both 100px) - at least one of them needs to be `height="*"` (default to rowdefinitions) in order for this to not look odd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" />  
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
        ...
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Comment: When I do that the whole application will fill up my screen, AND prevent me from downsizing it (just does its best to fill up the height of my desktop display.)